# Suppress year in as.Date in R

Tags: r, date

I am trying to create a date class without the year in R using a date and month. For example:

```
frame <- paste(c("March", "December", "January"), c(9,16,27))
as.Date(frame, format = "%B %d")
```

This automatically outputs the current year:

```
[1] "2014-03-09" "2014-12-16" "2014-01-27"
```

Is there any way to create a date class and suppress the year? I would like to do this in order to look through a frame of dates from multiple years to create a 'quarter' indicator. Thanks.

Comment: Try using `quarter()` from the `lubridate` package.

Comment: How about the `quarters` function for creating a 'quarter' indicator?  As in `quarters(as.Date(frame, format = "%B %d"))`

Comment: Great, many thanks - I didn't realize there was a quarters() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the way you are currently using `format` is for input. For formatting the output, try:

```
frame <- paste(c("March", "December", "January"), c(9,16,27))
format(as.Date(frame, format = "%B %d"), '%B %d')

[1] "March 09"    "December 16" "January 27"
```

which is exactly what you had wrapped in `format`